# integration table not working out for IBP

Tags: calculus, integration

Given $F'(x)=f(x)$ and $G'(x)=F(x)$, evaluate $\displaystyle \int_a^b xf(x)\ dx$, using the information on the following table.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
     x & f(x) & F(x) & G(x) \\
     \hline
     a & 2 & 4 & 10 \\
     \hline
     b & -1 & 5 & -11 \\
     \hline 
\end{array}

Here is where I went with it.

\begin{align*}
                            \int_a^b & xf(x)\ dx\\
                            u&=x\\
                            du&=x \,dx\\
                            dv&=f(x)\, dx\\
                            v&=F(x)\\
                            &=xF(x)\bigg\rvert_a^b - \int_a^b xF(x) \,dx\\
                            w&=x\\
                            dw&=x \,dx\\
                            dp&=F(x)\, dx\\
                            p&=G(x)\\
                            \int_a^b xf(x)\, dx &=xF(x)\bigg\rvert_a^b - \left(xG(x)\bigg\rvert_a^b-\int_a^b xG(x) \,dx\right)\\
                            \int_2^{-1} xf(x)\, dx &=xF(x)\bigg\rvert_4^5 - \left(xG(x)\bigg\rvert_{10}^{-11}-\int_{10}^{-11} xG(x) \,dx\right)\\
                        \end{align*}

But the equality is not working out at all. Did I do the IBP incorrectly? Currently looking to see if I can do anything with it before plugging the bounds in.

Comment: If $u = x$ then why is $du = xdx$?

Comment: just short hand same as saying $du = 1$ no?

Comment: Is $xdx$ the same as $dx$?

Comment: If $u=x$ and $du=\frac{du}{dx}dx$ and $\frac{du}{dx}=1$ then $du=dx$.

Comment: If $u=x$ then $du$ is NOT $x\,dx. \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $u=x$, then $du=1\,dx$, not $du=x\,dx$.

---

Hint.

$$
\int xF'(x)\,dx=xF(x)-\int F(x)\,dx=xF(x)-G(x)+C
$$

In general,
$$
\int f(x)g'(x)\,dx=f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)\,dx
$$

Comment: will work this out and check in desmos. ty!

Comment: I edited for proper MathJax usage.

Comment: obviously this worked. Thank you for your help. I am attempting to learn calc in 10 weeks with no experience so I feel like I'm missing a lot of small things everywhere. Appreciate the help!